# How do I post text area's content by click submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 style="color:#000000"> WELCOME TO TROLL CONTROLL </h1>
        </div>

  <div id="content">
            <textarea name="tmnl" id= "tmnl" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Please Share Your Story" > </textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name= "tmnlsubmit" id="tmnlsubmit" />

            <script> 
            var text = $('#tmnl').val(); 
            $('#tmnlsubmit').click(function(){
            $('#content').append(
                '<div class="post"> 
                </div> ');
                $('#content .post').html(<h2> + Post Title + </h2>
                        <p> + text + </p>);
                                            });
            </script>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</body>
```

I would like to be able be able to post the content of the textarea into the "content" div by creating a new div with each post. I tried everything and everytime I press submit nothing happens. Please help!

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 0):

All are good. `post_Title` variable was undeclared. And apply `$(.post)` is enough to insert html data.better to use `$(document).ready(function (){}`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#tmnlsubmit').click(function(){
       var Post_Title ="Post Title"
       var texts = $('#tmnl').val();
            $('#content').append('<div class="post"></div> ');
   $('.post').html('<h2>' +Post_Title+' </h2><p> '+ texts +' </p>');
                                           
     });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <h1 style="color:#000000"> WELCOME TO TROLL CONTROLL </h1>
        </div>

  <div id="content">
            <textarea name="tmnl" id= "tmnl" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Please Share Your Story" > </textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name= "tmnlsubmit" id="tmnlsubmit" />
<p class="post"></p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues with your code. Make following changes:

```
  <div id="content">
            <textarea name="tmnl" id= "tmnl" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Please Share Your Story" > </textarea>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name= "tmnlsubmit" id="tmnlsubmit" />
      </div>
  </div>

$('#tmnlsubmit').click(function(){
    var text = $('#tmnl').val();
  $('#content').append('<div class="post"></div>');
  $('#content').html('<h2>Post Title</h2><p>'+ text +'</p>');
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/)

Answer (score 0):

- You have missed some quotes.
- To avoid repeat post to all `.post` use `.append(div + h2 + p)`.
- I think you need to `.prepend()` to show new posts first.

```css
input,textarea{
display:block;
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 style="color:#000000"> WELCOME TO TROLL CONTROLL </h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <input id='title' name='title' placeholder='Title' />
    <textarea name="tmnl" id="tmnl" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Please Share Your Story"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="tmnlsubmit" id="tmnlsubmit" />

    <script>
      $('#tmnlsubmit').click(function() {
        var text = $('#tmnl').val();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        //use .prepend() instead of append to show new posts first
        $('#content').append('<div class="post">' +
          '<h2>' + title + '</h2><p>' + text + '</p>' + '</div>');
        //clear textarea
        $('#tmnl, #title').val("");
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great thank you, however i copied your code into dreamweaver and it still does nothing when I submit. Could it be a problem with my browser?

Comment: FIgured it out, had my jquery script at the bottom of the page, rookie mistake I guess, learning programming through youtube therefore I'm missing some principles.

Answer (score 0):

hi please review this code

```js
  $('#tmnlsubmit').on('click', function(e) {    
    var text = $('#tmnl').val();
    alert(text);
    
      $('#content').append("<div class='post'></div>");
      $('#content .post').html("<h2>Post Title</h2> <p> "+text +" </p>");
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 style="color:#000000"> WELCOME TO TROLL CONTROLL </h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <textarea name="tmnl" id="tmnl" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Please Share Your Story"> </textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="tmnlsubmit" id="tmnlsubmit" />
  </div>
</div>
```